# Does Dired have something like "New Folder with Selection" of macOS Finder?

Tags: dired

I want to create new folder then move file that is marked to that folder in emacs dired mode.

In macOS Finder, you can use the new folder with selection.

Is there a feature like this in emacs or emacs dired mode?

I'm using emacs 25.1.

Comment: See this related thread:  "**Emacs — dired copy / move files — create directory if needed**":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977014/emacs-dired-copy-move-files-create-directory-if-needed  For those people scratching their head (like me, until I Googled it), here is a link that describes the OSX feature:  http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/07/create-a-new-folder-containing-selected-items-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: Here is a link to the feature request **bug#22322:** -- other than the initial positive comment by the current Emacs maintainer (i.e., John W.), the Emacs team has not showed any interest in making this new proposed feature a reality; however, the draft solution by @lawlist in the link above has been serving his needs for the past year:  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2016-01/msg00238.html

Comment: @lawlist: Consider pinging the bug thread. It may not help, but it might.

Comment: @lawlist if your recommended function is enabled, dired-dwim-target is not working, Can you try it is working?

Comment: I have never used `dired-dwim-target` as non-nil, but would be pleased to look into it in the next few days -- perhaps earlier depending upon my work schedule.